# IIS express site not showing up in IIS after I try adding it through VS open website

Tags: asp.net, iis

In VS2013, I have a website I added to IIS express, thru the VS open website option. Yet when I look in my IIS manager, I do not see the website I added. When I do try to add a website through VS open website option, it adds my website to IIS sites, instead of IIS express. I'm guessing I have two versions of IIS and IIS express, that's conflicting. The website solution only seems to work correctly, running localhost:port 2045

How do I get my IIS manager to see my website, why isn't it showing up in IIS manager. Been stuck on this problem for days, any help would be useful.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Uploaded the external image and display it.

Comment: To see your site on IIS Express, you have to use a tool such as Jexus Manager, http://jexusmanager.com

Comment: Ill download it and try it out thanks lex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a website by Default VS 2013 creates it in IIS Express (since VS 2013 doesn't have Visual Studio Development Server like VS 2012). So to use local IIS there are 2 possibilities

For new website project:

File=>New=>Web Site

1)In the website creation wizard, change the Web location to HTTP and URL to a site already created in IIS then create a new application

For existing website project:

1)Right click website project in the VS=>Property Pages

2)Select Start Options

3)Select Use custom server (You should have a website with this website project)

Both of these options have their own issues so I would recommend to stick with default option i.e. IIS Express and then preferable publish the site (Right click project=>Publish web site ) in your local IIS

Comment: I'm trying your option 2 right now ravi, I choosed use custom server, but I'm confused what my "base URL" would be? shouldn't it be, http://localhost:2594/default.aspx? or just http://localhost:2594/?

Comment: It seems like my web solution only works correctly on IIS express localhost:2594, when I try to assign the web site to localhost using regular IIS  and VS, it gives me a SQL server error. An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\\Users\\bobdole\\Desktop\\VideoWebsite\\VideoWebsite\\VideoWebsite\\App_Data\\Database.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.  I have  SQL service running at localhost:2594 thats the database.

Comment: I'm thinking it has to do with my connectionstring, now that i changed it to regular IIS i need to make changes to my connectionstring, so it knows where the sql database is now, here is my old string, any clue how I should change it so it works with the regular IIS. <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\bobdole\Desktop\VideoWebsite\VideoWebsite\VideoWebsite\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: First you need to create a application in IIS https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28v=ws.10%29.aspx and say you create it on port 8080 so the base URL will be http://localhost:8080. Regarding the connection string error I am guessing you are running into error mentioned in this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis/ (localDB runs in usermode hence not accessible for applications deployed in IIS). So you may need to upgrade to SQL express.

Comment: is it possible to convert my sql express project to work in a sql express localDB?

Comment: I am not really sure of your question.Are you concerned on using SQL express with Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. I believe the database was made using sql express, so for some reason it only works on sql express on IIS express. But the problem like i said is my IIS manager only seems to detect the IIS site, not IIS express sites. I tried changing the binding in the application config file, but it only seems to work on IIS express not IIS site.